# Prevent packet injection

Tags: c#, c++, code-injection, packet

I want to develop an application written in C/C++/C# that can prevent packet injection for a specific application. It is something like anti cheating software.

On the cheater side, the scenario is like this: open the application (a game), then open the cheating application that spoof the packets sent by the game, inject them with fictional data and transmit those packets to server.

My goal is to design an application that can prevent packet injection for that specific game, but I have no idea where to start from.

Can anyone give a start point?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Why would cheaters want to run your application?

Comment: Thomas, I want to develop a launcher. The users won't be able to play on the server without launching the game from my app. Also, as I said, I want to code something that blocks packet injection.

Comment: I'm assuming you intend to use windows here...  It's almost impossible to do what you want to do because there are so many different ways to approach it.  You can inject packets at least 3 different ways that I can think of off the top of my head.  Layered service provider, a Winsock shim DLL and the TDI layer.  Then you get into the pcap type stuff...

Comment: you could sign/checksum the sensitive data at client side. But ultimately if the user has control over the game binary and the client machine you can't stop them from sending whatever they like. You'd probably need to move parts of the game engine/control to the server and treat the client as untrusted.

Answer (score -1):

Have the game use SSL (eg HTTPS). Your game client and the server will set up an encrypted channel of communication between themselves.

Comment: SSL is pretty expensive in processor resources and has a long startup and shutdown time.  Most games use UDP because the overhead of TCP is too much...

Comment: I don't know for sure. I want to develop this app for a friend of mine . If it helps, the game is World Of Warcraft. I've never played this game before and I don't know nothing about communication protocol.

Comment: @IonutUngureanu: You will have to turn off the Warden (Blizzards Anti Cheat tool) to have any effect and while it can be done it is not trivial.  Blocking packet injection is unrealistic on Windows.

Comment: But can I at least detect if the packet was injected? In this case I can kick the player from the server...

Comment: @IonutUngureanu: Not even close to 100%.  Again there are too many avenues by which a packet can be injected and some of them are so easy to do you'd spend all your time figuring out how people are managing to get past your defenses.  A better approach would be to validate the data in the packets.  For example, the Movement packet.  You know the char is at x & y and a move packet is sent that moves him to x+1000 & y.  Since he's on foot, that's an impossible move.  But if he were on a boat or a flying mount it may be possible.

Comment: Ok, I undestood. But is there a way to identify the app that is injecting the packets? I mean I have a copy of the app and I can check the actions that it takes. Can I scan for those actions in real time? I think of something similar to AV software...

Comment: @IonutUngureanu: Not 100%.  Consider the case of a shim Winsock DLL.  How would you know who put it there?  Or in the case of a thread injected into your process.  How do you know who injected the thread?